# Why Won't The Player Move With My Platform? (C#, Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make the player move while on top of a moving platform I made, but nothing I do works. The player simply stands on top of the platform without moving and slides off when it moves out from under them.

I currently have the program set up so that the player starts off in one screen, and they transition into the 2nd scene, which is where the platform is. What I'm trying to do is have the platform read any object with the "Character" tag, and either make it a child of the platform. or move it at the platform's speed. Here's my code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Character")
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
```

Comment: well does it become a child of the platform?

Comment: @BugFinder It does, but the player still doesn't move along with it.

Comment: then something else is wrong. because a child by default moves with the parent

Comment: The code looks right though. The "tag" is set up correctly in the editor right.  ?
and the "layer is do colliding with one another ?(you can check it in "ProjectSetting->Physics")

Comment: @KuroyukiHikari, what exactly are you asking me to check? I'm in the project settings < physics tab, but don't know what I specifically need to check for. The only thing I found was "Layer Collision Matrox" and "Cloth Inter-Collision".

Comment: something like this
https://connect-prd-cdn.unity.com/20190130/58b62f14-9833-4b28-944f-c57cca6c6ff3_physicsbestpractices01.png

check if the layers that you would like to collide with each other is "checked"

Comment: @KuroyukiHikari, I have something similar, but my objects aren't in it.